# Export animation in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, animation

I am getting an error when trying execute the task to export the animation which states

> Error: Image collection must have at least one image to create video (Error code: 3)

```
// Load the administrative boundary dataset for the entire world.
var adminBoundaries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

// Filter the dataset to get Afghanistan's administrative boundary.
var afghanistanBoundary = adminBoundaries.filterMetadata('COUNTRY_NA', 'equals', 'Afghanistan');

// Define the region of interest (ROI) as the boundary of Afghanistan.
var roi = afghanistanBoundary.geometry();

// Load the MODIS NDVI collection from 2005 to 2006.
var modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filterDate('2005-01-01', '2006-12-31')
                  .select('NDVI')
                  .filterBounds(roi);

// Define a function to add the date as a band to each image.
function addDate(image) {
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  var year = ee.Image(ee.Number(date.get('year'))).rename('year');
  return image.addBands(year);
}

// Map the addDate function over the collection.
var modisNDVIwithDate = modisNDVI.map(addDate);

// Define the visualization parameters for NDVI.
var ndviParams = {min: 0, max: 9000, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};

// Define the image collection to animate.
var collectionToAnimate = modisNDVIwithDate.select('NDVI').map(function(image) {
  return image.clip(roi).visualize(ndviParams).set('year', image.get('year'));
});

// Define the animation parameters.
var animationParams = {
  'dimensions': '720',
  'region': roi,
  'framesPerSecond': 2,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857'
};

// Create and download the video.
print('Generating and downloading the video...');
Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: collectionToAnimate,
  description: 'afghanistan_ndvi_animation',
  dimensions: animationParams.dimensions,
  framesPerSecond: animationParams.framesPerSecond,
  region: animationParams.region,
  crs: animationParams.crs,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Comment: Change COUNTRY_NA for country_na -- see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDOS_LSIB_SIMPLE_2017#table-schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your geometry is empty. The property name to filter should be 'country_na' instead of 'COUNTRY_NA'

[image]

Replace 5th line with

var afghanistanBoundary = adminBoundaries.filterMetadata('country_na', 'equals', 'Afghanistan');

It will work.

Comment: Thank you Oliver Lopez and Saumaya, it is working now